# Views Contextual Filter by current day

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am using the [Date Repeat Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_repeat_entity) module for generating a checklist for users.  I am able to use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display the list in chronological order for tasks relevant for the current user using a Contextual Filter.  Could I also use a Contextual Filter to only show the current nodes that have a date equal to the current date?

I would think this could be done by entering some PHP code as shown here: [image]

Comment: Instead of using contextual filter, have you tried using/adding regular FILTER (under FIELDS) ?

Comment: I'm not sure how a regular filter will be able to grab the current day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how a regular filter will be able to grab the current day

Add your date field to the filter.

You will then see this screen

[image]

Click apply and continue

[image]

Click on select a date, and select relative date

[image]

Put **today** as your relative date.

Comment: I have no idea where you got that first screen.  I have never seen it before.  This is now my date filter looks: [Imgur.](http://i.imgur.com/6h5gUix.png)  Are you running an additional module?  My data type is just a date.  Anyway I got the Contextual Filter to work with this code: [Imgur.](http://i.imgur.com/zgRNpEZ.png)  I am just testing it now with various formats.  I am really curious though about how you got this screen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5qILi.jpg

Comment: @KyleRiggen hummm, you have **Date Views** module enabled?

Comment: ah yes that was it.  Enabling Date Views gave me the extra screen and your filter works!  Thank you!