# Sorting Views by current week

Tags: 7, views, datetime

The [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) has functionality to filter dates with a granularity by Day, Months, Year, etc. but not for weeks.  So to do this with a Contextual Filter and PHP code to retrieve the current week, I tried this:[image]

This had an output that suggested the current week was the fifth of the year which would be in February as shown here:
[image]

Yet the output is correct without any filter as shown here:
[image]

With other PHP code to filter the View by days and months, it worked great.  Yet this week filter doesn't seem to know the current week of the year.  How can I either have the Date module filter with a granularity of weeks, or input the correct PHP code to have the list filter by the current week?

Comment: Do not use PHP inside of views... NEVEERR... Just remember one this quote next time you are using php inside of view... "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live"

Comment: Ironically, inside the view would be the easiest place for the next guy to see what's going on.

Comment: @darol100 So PHP inside a View is a security risk?  Not just a quality of life thing for maintainers?

Comment: You should never have any execute code in your database, that is huge security risk (including php and js). Also, php inside of views can have a a lot performance issue. Lastly, if the next developer have a syntax error inside of views the entire website is going to crash and you need to go directly to the database and fixed.

Comment: Using php views on a production site it just bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by using two separate filters.

The **first filter** will be a relative for the current day.  It should have an operator that is greater than or equal to today.

The **second filter** will be a relative day as well.  It will have an operator that is less than +7 days.

This will allow you to filter views by the current day plus seven days.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

same steps as [Views Contextual Filter by current day](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186372/views-contextual-filter-by-current-day)

except for relative date: put **week**

Comment: Ok what should the granularity be for that?  They all seem to output as blank.  [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/LLMMUX4.png)

Comment: humm ok, try putting **this week** or **Monday this week** or **Monday next week**

Comment: try with day as granularity.

Comment: **this week** allowed information to be displayed but it seemed to still only filter by which granularity was selected with the relative date of **this week**.  Here is by [Month](http://i.imgur.com/HQFaBvJ.png) that looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/e5P4El5.png).  Then your **day** suggestion does the same thing: [these settings](http://i.imgur.com/vvAn6eA.png) into [this display](http://i.imgur.com/JFcXD1G.png).

Comment: I found a similar question over at Stack Overflow [Any way to filter a view by week number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298273/any-way-to-filter-a-view-by-week-number)